# Send image url from ASP.NET WEB API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I  have my images into my images folder in my project and save the image name to my database. I can retrieve my images in my razor view like that.
where FoodImage is the name of the image and I've hardcoded the path (~/~/Images/FoodImage/{image name from database}).
code:-

```
<img src="~/Images/FoodImage/@Model.FoodImage" id="foodImage_upload_preview" alt="upload" width="250" height="150" />
```

Now I need to send this image URL via API from my server. But I don't know how to do that.

my apiend point: http://localhost:50833/api/getProducts
and response:

```
[
{
    "id": 16,
    "title": "Product Rafi+++",
    "description": "sdfsf",
    "sku": "sdfsdf",
    "cardImage": "01_01_2020_12_14_09jukka.jpg",
    "foodImage": "01_01_2020_12_14_09jukka.jpg",
    "price": 52
},
{
    "id": 17,
    "title": "rAFI",
    "description": "SDFSD",
    "sku": "fdf",
    "cardImage": "01_01_2020_12_35_41jukka.jpg",
    "foodImage": "01_01_2020_12_35_41jukka.jpg",
    "price": 52
}
]
```

So how can I send an image URL from my server?

Comment: Does the API return the name of the image file? If yes, then make a call to API from your controller and store in your view model, then iterate through results.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to hard code into the database. When uploading the file, you can simply store the path to the image.

So, when calling the `getProducts()` endpoint, you won't need to worry about the image path.

Example:

```
var imagePath= Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images", fileName);
//Upload the file
//Other logic
var product=new Product
{
foodImage=imagePath;
};
```